# How do you write a resolution of unity (the identity) in gauge theories?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, gauge-theory

In, say, a quantum field theory of a single scalar field $\phi$, it is common to write the identity as ${\bf 1}=\int{\cal D}\phi\, |\phi\rangle\langle \phi|$, a useful thing to do in various path integral manipulations.  Here, the path integral is over configurations of $\phi$ on some particular time slice.  For instance, you could break up a vacuum-to-vacuum amplitude through such an insertion at $t=0$, as in:
$$
\langle 0|U(\infty,-\infty)|0\rangle=\int{\cal D}\phi\,\langle 0|U(\infty,0) |\phi\rangle\langle \phi|U(0,-\infty)|0\rangle
$$
in order to compute the full amplitude in terms of the individual matrix elements $\langle \phi|U(0,-\infty)|0\rangle$ and $\langle 0|U(\infty,0) |\phi\rangle$, say.

How does the analogous thing work in gauge theories? In QED or YM, is it simply the naive thing, ${\bf 1}=\int{\cal D}A_\mu\, |A_\mu\rangle\langle A_\mu|$, or something more complicated?

I feel like it should be something more complicated for the usual reasons that gauge-theory path integrals over-count gauge-equivalent configurations, but I'm not sure how exactly the naive result should be modified.

Do you just need to go through the usual Faddeev-Popov procedure for each insertion of unity in a gauge-theory path integral? That is, is the right answer something more like ${\bf 1}=\int{\cal D}A_\mu\, |A_\mu\rangle\langle A_\mu|\delta(F[A])$ for some gauge-fixing functional $F[A]$?

**Edits:** edited to give more detail, examples.